# Increment Vote Securely with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I read many posts about this but didn't find a proper suggested, official way to secure the votes count.

How do we secure;

1. ***FieldValue.increment(1)*** so that malicious users cannot increment by 5,6 etc?
2. If we check for userID's (for ex; postID/likes/userIDs) How certain it is to check if it does not exist?
3. Could you please show the suggested, right way of creating a basic user likes/vote security structure example?

For Cloud Function suggestions; Is it really practical to run a Cloud Function for just one like or voting of any kind?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

> `FieldValue.increment(1)` so that malicious users cannot increment by 5,6 etc?

You can compare current value and new value in [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) as shown below:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.fieldName == resource.data.fieldName + 1;
```

From the documentation, *the `request.resource` variable contains the future state of the document* while `resource.data` is current values.

This however **does not** prevent user from using `increment(1)` multiple times. You must store user's UID somewhere to check that.

> If we check for userID's (for ex; postID/likes/userIDs) How certain it is to check if it does not exist?

You can use [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) function to check if user has already voted but you must ensure that the document is added at first place. User may increment the count but block the `create` operator that adds their vote's record allowing them to cast multiple votes.

One workaround would be to just add the vote document only instead of incrementing the count but then you'll have to read all the documents later to get total counts of votes or use Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions to keep the count updated in the background.

---

> Could you please show the suggested, right way of creating a basic user likes/vote security structure example?

When using Cloud Functions, it is ensured that the count will be incremented as well as the user's vote record is added and no one can reverse engineer the code.

Comment: So we can use; `!exists` and it is the suggested way of doing it, right?

Comment: @boorock you can but again, if user in anyway blocks the Firestore request that adds the vote document in your likes collection then the `!exists` will keep returning `true` and they'll still be able to vote again. So just ensure the document is created then it's the right way

Comment: Thank you, that was quite enlightening for me. So it looks like the only perfectly secure solution is still cloud functions . Now i see why there weren't an exact answer to this topic. Hope some firebase developers think on this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform all this from the client and using rules, no need for Cloud Functions.

- Client side: use a batch that

  1. Casts the vote
  2. Adds the user uid to some list
- Rules:

  1. Verify that the vote is properly casted (only increment by 1 for instance as suggested in the previous answer)
  2. Verify that the uid of the user is not already present in the list of casted votes but is present after using `!exists` and `existsAfter`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a Firebase Cloud Function to do the task for you.
These are server-side code (here, firebase), so no one could modify it.